# How to calculate a percentage by using the total of a column with data that is dynamic?

Tags: sql

```
Name        Value                Base      Percent  
Test123  (107,914.39)    1,437,926.00   (Test123value *100)/Total of Base
Test124  (265,295.33)    7,023,337.00   (Test124value *100)/Total of Base
Test125  (622,284.16)    6,507,745.20   (Test125value *100)/Total of Base
```

What procedure can accomplish that "Percent" column?

FYI..... the data for these are not static it just pulls whatever it has from the table.

Thanks

Comment: I'm using SQL code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select value * 100/ sum(base) over () as percent
```